# DbContext doesn't update properties of objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

We have a global `DataManager` that holds and manages a single `DbContext`.

We bind all the objects of a table called `File` to a tree view.

```
return this.ArchiveContext.File.Where(f => f.parent_id == null).ToList<File>();
```

New items get updated with the data binding, which is great.
Unfortunately, properties like the `name` don't.

We figured it's probably best to just update them every x seconds.
We also found out that, unless the context is recreated, none of the properties will get updated.

This is obviously the wrong approach.

What are the best practises when working with `DbContext`?

Comment: How are you trying to update properties? Are you binding it on XAML?

Comment: Best practice is to construct and dispose of `DbContext` as you need it, deep inside your data access layer.

Comment: @KeithPayne A call of `SaveChanges` will not save any changes when mutating the models. How can I solve this?

Comment: @KeithPayne It depends on the design of software. That shouldn't be problem if their requirements are met of storing static dbContext.

Comment: @NSAddict it is because you do not have proxy classes anymore so that DbContext doesn't not track of your objects.

Comment: @kkocabiyik I see why it's happening, but how can I fix that? I've read before that you should generally just use the `DbContext` on the fly

Comment: You should keep the proxy objects and also implement INotificationPropertyChanged on your classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using completely different array of objects when you use ToList() returning from your static dbcontext. Assuming you show your array of objects in a List or something like List. You may set DataSource property with newly allocated object, and it will refresh all your list.

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = NewList;
```